How determine whether a quad of a grid mesh is too steep to move onto, without using a NavMesh?
Godot 4.1
Assume we've got a simple, 100x100 cells grid-based generated mesh that will serve as the game's level:

This mesh is exported as either .obj or .glb and imported in Godot.
The player (represented as the red cube) can move in 8 directions in increments of 1 metre. In other words, the player is always bound to the middle of the cell they are moving into.
Player also has the limit of how steep of a slope they can traverse.
I.e. in the image below, the player would be able to move into the mild slopes denoted with green check marks, but steep cliffs would act as walls:

Now, the check needs to be made to see if the slope the player is moving into is traversable or too steep.
This is the way I envision the algorithm:

Map the XY grid coordinates where the player wants to move to the respective position on the 3D level mesh. Trivial, as 3D mesh is aligned to the grid 1:1.

Check the Z-coordinate of the XY position on the level's 3D mesh that the player wants to move to.

Subtract from the player's current Z-position. If the difference is too high, do not move.

If the difference is acceptable, calculate the Z-position of the middle of the cell using that quad's vertex coordinates.

Move the player to the new XYZ.


Desired Result:

Is there a way to implement this in Godot without using NavMesh generation?
I.e. using the .obj or .glb vertex data only?

The MeshInstance3D node has a method get_mesh that gives you a Mesh object. This object can be used to access the raw geometry data of a 3d model. In your case, the get_faces() method is probably the most interesting one.
As your mesh is essentially a heightmap of equal sized squares, I would use the data from this array of vectors to build an own 2d array of map cells with their two triangles and the height of their corners. That way you can quickly obtain the triangle at any given 2d map coordinate-pair by looking it up in the 2d array. You can then interpolating the height between the corner points to get the accurate height on any position within the triangle, or calculate the difference between the corner points to get the slope steepness.

There is something that is bothering me about this question, specifically:

The question is being asked as if each grid location has a height.
However the mesh defines the height of the 4 corners of each grid location (not the center of the grid itself).

Most likely each grid square is actually being rendered using two triangles hence the (center) height of the grid is the average of only two points (looking at the images - I think it's the top and bottom points).
Assuming everything I have said is correct, you could just average the correct two points for the current location and do the same for each of the eight directions, in order to determine the gradient for each possible move. However because you are only using two (of the four) points to determine the height of each grid location I suspect there will be some weird artifacts where the game will allow some moves that look like they should not be possible.

Cutting to the chase, given the importance of the height of the terrain to determine which routes are passable I would consider rethinking how the maps are draw so that:

The height of each grid square is clearly displayed.
Its obvious which directions are passable.
The grid "squares" are still clear.

One possible answer may be to double the number of vertices horizontally and vertically that way the center of each grid can be on a vertex and you will have 8 intermediate vertices (one for each movement direction) between the current location and the center of each of the adjacent squares - which will allow you to smooth the heights of of those points read: the intermediate point is just the average of the current and adjacent square.
You may also want to layout the triangle pattern slightly differently, for example a single "doubled up" grid square could have 8 triangles:
+--+--+
|\ | /|
| \|/ |
+--+--+
| /|\ |
|/ | \|
+--+--+

The "problem" with this approach is, your grid "Squares" now have 8 sides....
